# How do you switch the audio playback device on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

With Windows 10 it was easy to right click the audio icon in the system tray and choose the desired output device.

Now you get a completely different menu.
[image: audio menu]

Is there a new easy way to switch the output that I'm missing?

Comment: They have combined Audio Settings into the main Settings app. Either left or right click and go to Audio settings in the main Settings app. That is part of the Windows 11 re-design.

Answer (score 0):

OK, stumbled on the answer to this myself today. I thought hope was lost and luckily was wrong.

- Click the audio icon in the tray and then click the chevron icon to the right of the volume slider.
  [image: slider menu click]
- Then pick an audio device!
  [image: device picker]
- 